# Jenkins pipeline git checkout access GIT_COMMIT when default checkout is skipped

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

**Observations:**

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { node 'master' }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo env.GIT_COMMIT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
[Pipeline] echo
e5b4b2deed1c8db486cef5641ef14c61fd48f9ed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { node 'master' }
    
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '/tmp/r']]])
                echo env.GIT_COMMIT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/HelloWorld_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/HelloWorld_master/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url /tmp/r # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from /tmp/r
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- /tmp/r +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e5b4b2deed1c8db486cef5641ef14c61fd48f9ed (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e5b4b2deed1c8db486cef5641ef14c61fd48f9ed # timeout=10
Commit message: "init"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

**Question:**

I am using jenkins version 2.349 and the project is of type Multi-branch pipeline.

As I read on the Jenkins git plugin's [page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/), it is supposed to inject the environment variables but it seems it only does when the default checkout isn't skipped but not when we explicitly checkout. I could only find ways to access those SCM values (in my case GIT_COMMIT) by using a script { } block. Is there a way to get those variables without jumping into a script block?

Answer (score 0):

The checkout() call returns an object with a commit property:

```
def result = checkout(...)
echo "Commit: ${result.GIT_COMMIT}"
```

Note that this may depend on the version of the git plugin installed.

Comment: I think this requires to go into a script block. The question was how could it be done without going into a script block.

Comment: In a multibranch pipeline Jenkins will add an implicit stage in the pipeline that will (1) perform the checkout then (2) set the GIT_* environment variables based on that checkout. 

If the skipDefaultCheckout() option is specified then your pipeline must perform the checkout() step. But that step by itself does not set any GIT_* environment variables. Instead it returns an object containing the git information, which you may then use directly or inject into the environment if you wish.

I'm not sure why avoiding a script block is a concern here?